# i had a data in table in UI i want to convert that tabular data into save as pdf

Tags: java

I had a data in table in UI. I want to convert that tabular data into save as pdf.

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: datatables has an extension that will do this job for you. search for that.
[see here](https://datatables.net/reference/button/pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Create and save a PDF file that contains the data from the table

https://datatables.net/reference/button/pdf

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'pdf',
            text: 'Save current page',
            exportOptions: {
                modifier: {
                    page: 'current'
                }
            }
        }
    ]
} );
```